# Need join query for mulitple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I want to fetch the data from multiple tables which display the outputs as shown in below. I have tried to write sql query but it’s giving me wrong data.

Following are the fields of the table.

```
 1. table1 : id, name
 2. table2: id, table1_id
 3. table3: id, name
 4. table4: id, table3_id, table2_id
```

Output Should be like below:

**table1 name field (Total Count of below 3 records = e.g. 9)**

```
 1. Record 1 (Table 3 name) (Count from Table 4 = e.g. 4)
 2. Record 2 (Table 3 name)  (Count from Table 4 = e.g. 2)
 3. Record 3 (Table 3 name)  (Count from Table 4 = e.g. 3)
```

Above data will continue in loop for next records.

I want to build array which will give the result in single join query. I have tried below one but it’s not working.

```
SELECT SUM(table1.id) as Total 
  FROM table1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2 
    ON table2.id = table1.type_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table4 
    ON table4.table2_id = table1.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table3 
    ON table3.id = table4.table3_id 
 GROUP 
    BY table2.id
     , table3.id
```

Please help me for this one.

Thanks

Comment: Left joining tables from which you select no columns is essentially pointless.

Comment: Have a look at how others here have asked questions, and amend yours accordingly.

Comment: rather than selecting sum at your query first aim at the retrieving records for debugging your query.

Comment: `It's not working` is the singularly most useless phrase I read on SO.  Are you getting error messages?  If so, what are they?  Are you getting unexpected results?  If so, please provide ***everything*** we need to replicate what you're getting *(Sample data that covers important corner cases for your requirements, your query, the results you **actually get** and the results you **want**.)*